# get notified when screen becomes visible in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

The answer I expected at first was the show method. Unfortunately if show has a lot of work to do, there is a delay between method call and screen appearance. So how does one get notified when screen appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `show()` should be fine, the screen will be shown straight after so just put stuff you want done at the end where the delay should be negligible.

If the work that `show()` does is in a super class, then just override it, call `super.show()` and then do your stuff after, like so...

```
@Override
public void show () {
    super.show();
    doAnyOtherSlowStuffThatMightNeedDoing();
    doTimeCriticalStuff();
}
```

I should probably add that a better solution would be to not do slow stuff in the `show()` method to start with, but that's a whole other debate.